# Regresiones a partir de un Data Frame

Tags: base-de-datos, dataframe

He creado un data.frame con las siguientes variables aleatorias:

```
**set.seed(1:50)
df_1 = replicate(50,{
  x1 = c(t(runif(100,min=0, max=100)))
  x2 = c(t(runif(100,min=0, max=100)))
  x3 = (c(t(runif(100,min=0, max=100)))*(-1))
  u  = c(t(rnorm(100,0,40)))
  y = 300 + x1 + x2 + x3 + u
  dfa <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,u,y)})**
```

df_1 es una base que contiene 250 vectores con 100 obs cada una

¿Como puedo hacer para correr una regresion desde el data frame creado (no desde el proceso de replicate), es decir lm(y ~ x1+x2+x3) y guardar los coeficientes B0, B1,B2, y B3 en un data.frame? La idea es que me queden una matriz con 4 por 50 Betas.